# Cannot access to spring boot admin from gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, gateway, spring-boot-admin

I cannot access to my microservice spring admin dashboard from my gateway, but it works from the direct link (spring-dashboard) link .

The problem appear with the new version of spring boot admin dashboard , it looks like a Cors origin problem :

```js
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9091/applications' from origin 'http://localhost:8083' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

### Capture of Spring dashboard from gateway

[image]

### Capture of Spring dashboard from it's own link

[image]

Project Link : https://github.com/SeifBh/spring-project

Any idea?

Comment: another issue with same problem dosen't solved yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951506/cannot-access-to-spring-boot-admin-from-gateway

Answer (score 0):

If using **Chrome**, Try adding either `extension`:
[Allow CORS - Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) , [Allow CORS - Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

**OR**

If you don't want to add extension to **Chrome** , you can open **Chrome** via console (you should close all the **Chrome** windows first):

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

**OR**

If using **Firefox**, Try adding `add-on` : [Allow CORS - Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/)

---

If you want to fix it in code, You need to add below configuration :

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/resource")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
        }
    };
}
```

Check the `Spring Docs` : [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Comment: thanks for your answer , but this is a bad practice ! something in the code should be updated !

Comment: @SeifBh : you need to configure it . updated the answer with example. please make a try.

Answer (score 0):

You will be getting some UI related errors in browser console/network tab. For accessing spring boot admin via zuul, you need to specify property `spring.boot.admin.ui.public-url` , the value of the property will be your zuul host.
Checkout [this](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#_running_behind_a_front_end_proxy_server) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You must migrate your project to Spring Cloud Gateway.

The following Spring Cloud Netflix modules and corresponding starters will be placed into maintenance mode:

spring-cloud-netflix-archaius
spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-contract
spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard
spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream
spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix
spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon
spring-cloud-netflix-turbine-stream
spring-cloud-netflix-turbine
spring-cloud-netflix-zuul

More information in this link: https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/12/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc1-available-now#spring-cloud-netflix-projects-entering-maintenance-mode

You must follow this example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/gateway/

Good luck

Joe